# Sending data via Bluetooth using StreamSocket

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, iostream

I wanted to transmit an array over Bluetooth using Windows Phone 8, so I referred to the following intro guide on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx

Pairing/Connecting was pretty straightforward and when I deployed the app to my Lumia 620 I was able to see my paired HTC Desire using the sample code in the above. So next I tried sending a basic 5-byte array using the following code:

```
async void BLEfunc()
    {
        PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
        var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

        if (peers.Count == 0)
        {
            Details.Text = "No Device Found";
        }
        else
        {
            PeerInformation selectedPeers = peers[0];
            StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
            await socket.ConnectAsync(selectedPeers.HostName, "1");
            Details.Text = "Connected to device: " + selectedPeers.DisplayName;  //Details is a TextBlock on screen

            using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
            {
                //byte[] DataArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                dataWriter.WriteByte(1);
                var result = await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                dataWriter.DetachStream();
            }
            Details.Text = "Data sent!";
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the program runs into an unhandled exception when it enters the using code block in the above pasted code. Everything up to that point runs fine. I got the idea for the above code from here: [Sending files via bluetooth from winRT to android / WP devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140947/sending-files-via-bluetooth-from-winrt-to-android-wp-devices)

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find any solution ? I have same issue

Comment: Unfortunately no. The Windows Phone 8 APIs aren't very well documented or used. I wanted to send/receive data in the background too so I ended up switching to Windows Phone 8.1. It has a different set of classes for communicating with devices via Bluetooth 4.0 and it works well.

Comment: if it worked please send a repro of your codes or upload a sample for it . Thanks