# Send data through Bluetooth windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10, win-universal-app

I cannot figure out how to communicate between two devices running Windows universal apps for Windows 10, using Bluetooth. I'm not sure if there is something with my research, but I couldn't find anything  on the API.

Can someone guide me quickly through this using C#?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this MSDN link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm

This example shows client and server model Bluetooth communication.

For device enumeration and pairing, you can use this Windows samples:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing

This sample will not work in old Windows SDK versions (10240).

For file transfer, you have to implement IrOBEX protocol connect, disconnect and data packets as in the document.

I think the steps will be like this:

1. Enumerate and pair using windows sample.
2. open a stream socket.
3. Implement the OBEX protocol.

Something like this:

```
private static byte[] CreateConnectPacketOPP(int maxPacketSize)
{
    int packetSize = 7;
    byte[] theConnectPacket = new byte[packetSize];

    int offset = 0;
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = 0x80;                                   // Connect
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = (byte)((packetSize & 0xFF00) >> 8);     // Packetlength Hi Byte
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = (byte)(packetSize & 0xFF);              // Packetlength Lo Byte
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = 0x10;                                   // Obex v1
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = 0x00;                                   // No flags
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = (byte) ((maxPacketSize & 0xFF00) >> 8); // 2048 byte client max packet size Hi Byte
    ConnectPacket[offset++] = (byte) (maxPacketSize & 0xFF);          // 2048 byte max packet size Lo Byte    

    return ConnectPacket;
}
```